# Use Chosen jQuery plugin in MVC Asp Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would to install Chosen javascript jquery plugin in a AspNet project. I have followed this step:

1- under Scripts directory I have added all the javascript file as the image below

[image]

2- in the Index.cshtml I have added

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chosen: A jQuery Plugin by Harvest to Tame Unwieldy Select Boxes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/chosen_v1.8.2/docsupport/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/chosen_v1.8.2/docsupport/prism.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/chosen.css">
    @*<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src &apos;self&apos;; script-src &apos;self&apos; https://ajax.googleapis.com; style-src &apos;self&apos;; img-src &apos;self&apos; data:">*@
</head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen_v1.8.2/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen_v1.8.2/docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

 <script src="~/Scripts/chosen_v1.8.2/docsupport/init.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Then I added the multiselection ui but it still doesn't work. I get always the ui in the image below:

[image]

Any suggestion?
Thank in advance.

Comment: change the order of script because  i had a problem , sometime Jquery   Should be load before any other lib

Comment: Please add your HTML markup, we need to see what your standard `<select>` element looks like

Comment: Your scripts seem to be floating in no man's land, either put them in your head or your body, not between them (not sure if that'll make any difference though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually initialize the chosen library on your select component. This is best done in the document ready event to make sure the library is loaded.

By for example adding this in your html code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("select").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure who downvoted your answer but I believe its correct. However if you are going to mention the ready() method in your question you should really add it to your code snippet. Also OP's JS scripts are not contained in the <head> tags although strangely their css links are.

Comment: @charlietfl Fair enough, but thats not immediately obvious to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

thank you for your answer, now is working.
I would like to share step by step the procedure that I have followed:

1. Download Chosen from website  https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen, in my case chosen_v1.8.2
2. Create and populate the directory inside the ASP-NET project as follow

   Scripts/chosen put here all the file in \chosen_v1.8.2
   Scripts/chosen/docsupport put here all the file in \chosen_v1.8.2\docsupport

   5- Update /App_Start/ BundleConfig.cs

//add chosen script

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/chosen").Include(
    "~/Scripts/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/chosen/chosen.jquery.js",
    "~/Scripts/chosen/docsupport/prism.js",
    "~/Scripts/chosen/docsupport/init.js"
```

3. Update /shared/Layout.cshtml

After jquery add the chosen bundle

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/chosen")
```

Update /shared/Layout.cshtml Add after jquery the chosen bundle

5.Update index.cshtml with some samples

...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("select").chosen();
            $("chosen-select-width").chosen();

       });
    </script>

<h2><a name="custom-width-support" class="anchor" href="#custom-width-support">Select the shop</a></h2>
<div class="side-by-side clearfix">
    <p>Using a custom width with Chosen is as easy as passing an option when you create Chosen:</p>
    <pre><code class="language-javascript"> $(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "95%"}); </code></pre>
    <div>
        <em>Multiple Select Shop id</em>
        <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" multiple class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="16">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option selected>Test1</option>
            <option>Test2</option>
            <option>Test3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

7 Enjoy