# Creating a field for multiselect dropdown based on self (without creating a new model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get a multiselect dropdown feature implemented for my BugTracker, and can't seem to find a solution that doesn't involve creating another model. Here's how it works:

I have a model named Report, which contains information about a bug. This model contains fields such as bug name, urgency, date submitted, solution, etc. What I want is to add a field that would actually be a list of related bugs. Thus, when the programmer is updating this report, he can select from a list of previous bugs (reports) and add multiple report numbers. When the report is viewed (not edited), these numbers will appear as an ActionLink to the report page. So maybe the user sees this:

RelatedBugs: 1, 37, 56

And the code behind it would be like this:

RelatedBugs: @Html.ActionLink("1", "Admin", "Report", 1, null), @Html.ActionLink("37", "Admin", "Report", 37, null), @Html.ActionLink("56", "Admin", "Report", 56, null)

(Where these numbers are actually the ID of the Report.cs from below.)

So on the Edit View of the form, there would be a multiselect dropdown where you can pick all of these bugs. This would be similar to https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/, where in the multiselect area you can see a list of all the bugs/reports and their associated IDs. Or even just a list of the IDs!

And on the typical view, you'd see what you have above.

What can I do to get this working properly?

Let me give you my own code to show you what I mean (code significantly cut to make the question easier):

*Report.cs (model)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BugTracker.Models
{
    public class Report
    {
        //For User
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public String Solution { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

*AdminReport.cshtml (View)*

```
@model BugTracker.Models.Report
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
Description: @Model.Description <br /> <br />
Solution: @Model.Solution    <br /> <br>
```

And the form used for editing...

*AdminReportForm.cshtml*

```
@model  BugTracker.ViewModels.UserReportViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Issue Form";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Update Issue</h1>    
@Model.Report.Name <br />    
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAdmin", "Report"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Solution</label>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Report.Solution, new { @class = "form-control", @rows="10"})
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Report.ID)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

My viewmodel (the real ViewModel contains several additional fields):

*UserReportViewModel.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BugTracker.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BugTracker.ViewModels
{
    public class UserReportViewModel
    {
        public Report Report { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

Controllers...

*(For AdminReport.cshtml)*

```
    public ActionResult Admin(int id)
    {
        var report = _context.Reports.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);
        if (report == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        var viewModel = new UserReportViewModel
        {
            Report = report,
        };

        return View("AdminReport", report);
    }
```

*For AdminReportForm.cshtml*

```
    public ActionResult EditAdmin(int id)
    {
        var report = _context.Reports.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);
        if (report == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        var viewModel = new UserReportViewModel
        {
            Report = report,
        };

        return View("AdminReportForm", viewModel);
    }
```

And finally my Post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult SaveAdmin(UserReportViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.Report.ID == 0)
            _context.Reports.Add(viewModel.Report);
        else
            var reportInDb = _context.Reports.Single(c => c.ID == viewModel.Report.ID);

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ReportAll", "Report");

    }
```

Comment: I appreciate you've asked how to get this working properly, but I wonder if readers might need more guidance on the kind of help you are seeking. For example, is this a UI design problem? A SQL/database/model/join problem? What does your code do presently, and how is it different to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Collection of Reports to your view model?
Then you can use linq to filter the reports and populate the Dropdown.

```
namespace BugTracker.ViewModels
{
    public class UserReportViewModel
    {
        public Report Report { get; set; }
        public List<Report> Reports {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this idea! This would be perfect for the form view in which the user can select multiple reports. But then, what would I use for my Report Model to hold the values that the user selected?

Comment: Making progress. As recommended, I used the suggestion:

public List<Report> Reports {get; set;}

To actually save the data, I have added the following in my Report model:

public Virtual ICollection<Report> Reports {get; set;}

That said, I'm still struggling on the form..

I'm trying to do something like this:
`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Reports, new MultiSelectList(Model.Reports, "ID", "Name"), "Select Priority", new { id = "relatedbugs", multiple = "multiple" })`

However, I'm not quite sure how I could access my list with this. What's the proper way to do this line of code?

Comment: "But then, what would I use for my Report Model to hold the values that the user selected?" You can add as many objects to your view model that you need. Create another list, List<Report> SelectedReports. Then in your post controller, you can pass that object into your context and update the database.

Comment: Instead of the @html.DropDownList, why not use Tag Helper?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally resolve this issue - thanks for all the help, everyone! Here was how I resolved it:

First, in my "*Report.cs*" file, I added the following:

```
public String RelatedBugs {get; set;}
public String[] RelatedBugsArray {get; set;}
```

In my view model "*UserReportViewModel.cs*", I added the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Report> Report {get; set;}
```

The form gave me some issues. I initially used a DropDownBoxFor, but for multiselect you actually need to use ListBoxFor (it will still work with the DropDownBoxFor, but the problem is it can't pre-populate it when you try to edit the form.) So, in *AdminReportForm.cshtml*, I have the following:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Report.RelatedBugsArray, new MultiSelectList(Model.Reports, "ID", "Name"), new {id = "relatedbugs"})
```

To use the chosen script, I first set it up by using this link: [Use Chosen jQuery plugin in MVC Asp Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436081/use-chosen-jquery-plugin-in-mvc-asp-net)

In the same report from, I made my ListBoxFor utilize my Chosen script with this:

```
@section scripts{
<script>
$(function () {
$("#relatedbugs").chosen();
});
</script>
}
```

Now, all that is left is the controller. There are two actions I care about: the edit and the save action. The EditAdmin and Admin actions will have the same code:

```
if (report.RelatedBugs != null)
     report.RelgatedBugsArray = report.RelatedBugs.Split(',');
```

For the SaveAdmin action, we just need to do this:

```
if (viewModel.Report.RelatedBugsArray == null)
     viewModel.Report.RelatedBugs = null;
else
     viewModel.Report.RelatedBugs = string.Join(",", viewModel.Report.RelatedBugsArray);
```

Basically, what we are doing is taking the Report IDs as an array and putting them into a string with a comma between each element. When we go to feed it back to the view, convert the string to an array by splitting each element between the commas.

Thanks again for all the suggestions!